options.providers is not iterable http://localhost:3000/api/auth/error
Trying to build a full stack web app with next-auth but having trouble with logging in, it takes me to http://localhost:3000/api/auth/error. However, my signup works and i see users getting added in DB. Any help at all would be appreciate please
Here is my auth.ts:
import NextAuth, { NextAuthOptions } from "next-auth";
import CredentialsProvider from "next-auth/providers/credentials";
import { PrismaAdapter } from "@next-auth/prisma-adapter"
import { db } from "./db";
import { compare } from "bcrypt";

export const authOptions: NextAuthOptions = {
    adapter: PrismaAdapter(db), //prisma 
    secret: process.env.NEXTAUTH_SECRET,
    session:{
        strategy: 'jwt' //using json web token
    },
    pages:{
        signIn: '/sign-in',
        //signout: here
    },
    providers: [
        CredentialsProvider({
          // The name to display on the sign in form (e.g. "Sign in with...")
          name: "Credentials",
          // `credentials` is used to generate a form on the sign in page.
          // You can specify which fields should be submitted, by adding keys to the `credentials` object.
          // e.g. domain, username, password, 2FA token, etc.
          // You can pass any HTML attribute to the <input> tag through the object.
          credentials: {
            email: { label: "Username", type: "email", placeholder: "Email" },
            password: { label: "Password", type: "password" }
          },
          async authorize(credentials, req) {
            if(!credentials?.email || !credentials?.password){  //if crendentials or email empty return null dont give access to or session
                return null;
            }
            const existingUser = await db.user.findUnique({
                where: {email: credentials?.email}
            });
            if(!existingUser){
                return null;
            }

            const passwordMatch = await compare(credentials.password, existingUser.password);

            if(!passwordMatch){
                return null;
            }

            return {
                id: `${existingUser.id}`,
                username: existingUser.username,
                email: existingUser.email,
            }

          }
        })
    ],
    callbacks:{
      async jwt({token, user}){
        //console.log(token,user);
        if(user){
          return{
            ...token,
            username: user.username
          }
        }
        return token
      },
      async session({session, token}){
        return{
          ...session,
          user: {
            ...session.user,
            username: token.username
          }
        }
      },
    }
}

Here is my SignInForm.tsx
'use client';

import { useForm } from 'react-hook-form';
import {
  Form,
  FormControl,
  FormField,
  FormItem,
  FormLabel,
  FormMessage,
} from '../ui/form';
import * as z from 'zod';
import { zodResolver } from '@hookform/resolvers/zod';
import { Input } from '../ui/input';
import { Button } from '../ui/button';
import Link from 'next/link';
import GoogleSignInButton from '../GoogleSignInButton';
import { signIn } from 'next-auth/react'; 
import { useRouter } from 'next/navigation';

const FormSchema = z.object({
  email: z.string().min(1, 'Email is required').email('Invalid email'),
  password: z
    .string()
    .min(1, 'Password is required')
    .min(6, 'Password must have than 6 characters'),
});

const SignInForm = () => {
  const router = useRouter();
  const form = useForm<z.infer<typeof FormSchema>>({
    resolver: zodResolver(FormSchema),
    defaultValues: {
      email: '',
      password: '',
    },
  });

  const onSubmit = async (values: z.infer<typeof FormSchema>) => {
    const signInData = await signIn("credentials", {
      email: values.email,
      password: values.password,
      redirect: false,
    });
    if (signInData?.error) {
      console.log("error----", signInData.error);
    } else {
      router.push("/admin");
    }
  };

  return (
    <Form {...form}>
      <form onSubmit={form.handleSubmit(onSubmit)} className='w-full'>
        <div className='space-y-2'>
          <FormField
            control={form.control}
            name='email'
            render={({ field }) => (
              <FormItem>
                <FormLabel>Email</FormLabel>
                <FormControl>
                  <Input placeholder='mail@example.com' {...field} />
                </FormControl>
                <FormMessage />
              </FormItem>
            )}
          />
          <FormField
            control={form.control}
            name='password'
            render={({ field }) => (
              <FormItem>
                <FormLabel>Password</FormLabel>
                <FormControl>
                  <Input
                    type='password'
                    placeholder='Enter your password'
                    {...field}
                  />
                </FormControl>
                <FormMessage />
              </FormItem>
            )}
          />
        </div>
        <Button className='w-full mt-6' type='submit'>
          Sign in
        </Button>
      </form>
      <div className='mx-auto my-4 flex w-full items-center justify-evenly before:mr-4 before:block before:h-px before:flex-grow before:bg-stone-400 after:ml-4 after:block after:h-px after:flex-grow after:bg-stone-400'>
        or
      </div>
      <GoogleSignInButton>Sign in with Google</GoogleSignInButton>
      <p className='text-center text-sm text-gray-600 mt-2'>
        If you don&apos;t have an account, please&nbsp;
        <Link className='text-blue-500 hover:underline' href='/sign-up'>
          Sign up
        </Link>
      </p>
    </Form>
  );
};

export default SignInForm;

here is my app/pages/api/auth/[...nextauth]/route.ts
import { authOptions } from "@/lib/auth";
import NextAuth from "next-auth"

const handler = NextAuth({authOptions});

export { handler as GET, handler as POST};

And lastly here is my app/pages/api/user
import { db } from "@/lib/db";
import { NextResponse } from "next/server";
import { hash } from 'bcrypt';
import * as z from 'zod'

// Define schema for input validate
const userSchema = z
  .object({
    username: z.string().min(1, 'Username is required').max(100),
    email: z.string().min(1, 'Email is required').email('Invalid email'),
    password: z
      .string()
      .min(1, 'Password is required')
      .min(6, 'Password must have than 6 characters'),
  });

export async function POST(req: Request){
    try{
        const body = await req.json();
        const {email,username,password} = userSchema.parse(body);

        // Check if email already exist
        const existingUserByEmail = await db.user.findUnique({
            where: {email : email}
        });
        if(existingUserByEmail){
            return NextResponse.json({user:null,message:"user with email already exist"}, {status:409})
        }

        // Check if user name already exist
        const existingUserByUsername = await db.user.findUnique({
            where: {username : username}
        });
        if(existingUserByUsername){
            return NextResponse.json({user:null,message:"user with username already exist"}, {status:409})
        }

        //Store data in db
        const hashPassword = await hash(password,6); //default 5 characters
        const newUser = await db.user.create({
            data: {
                username,
                email,
                password: hashPassword,
            }    
        })

        const { password: newUserPassword, ...rest} = newUser;

        return NextResponse.json({user: newUser, message: "User Created successfully"}, {status:201});

    }catch(error){    
        return NextResponse.json({message: "Something went wrong"}, {status:500});
    }
}

